# Insert/update Dynamics/Dataverse N:N relationship intersect table

Tags: azure-data-factory

Is it possible to to insert/update intersect table in Dynamics/Dataverse that contains the actual data for N:N relationships?

Using the copy activity I can copy the content of that table (nothing more than a bunch of GUIDs) but trying to insert/update data in that table returns a nondescript error.

Dataflow will not even allow the intersect table as a source and will trow a nondescript error on retrieving the projection.

The docs make no mention of what is and isn't supported as far as the Dynamics/Dataverse sink goes.

Comment: did you find a way around this ?

Comment: No I did not. I haven't had time to contact MS support yet though I did ask a vendor we work with and they said this basically is not possible unless you start working with custom plugins.

Comment: You can probably post this finding as an answer and [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem

Comment: Which finding? You said you believe there is a flag at the dynamics end (I am unable to find such a setting). Our 3rd party said it cannot be done without a custom plugin and Microsoft support has yet to come back with a reply.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is feature flag at dynamics end to enable upsert for N:N relationship entities. As I could not find a detailed take on this scenario in the docs, I would suggest you raise a feedback [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/new) or reach out to MS support if not already done.